# How to configure automatic pushing?

Tags: git, mercurial

How do I configure automatic push in Mercurial and Git?
Sometimes I forgot to push in a computer, and when I move my location, I'm out of the sync with the good code. Is there a way to mercurial and git do this every hour, for instance?

Comment: It's worth noting here that it's a better idea to just learn to push. You really don't want to push after every commit. If you do this, you break some of git's best tools -- you cut yourself off from rebase, `commit --amend`, and other great history-editing tools.

Comment: Just noting that our team lead insists on having developer's local repositories mirrored on a server just for the point of having a live backup; they aren't actually part of our day-to-day process.

Comment: Open your minds. I use source control even when I'm working alone. And I work on different computers.

Comment: Just sometimes that is convenient to me use automatic pushing. I turn off later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In mercurial you'd put this in your `.hg/hgrc`

```
[hooks]
commit = hg push
```

Answer (score 20):

With git you can use the `post-commit` hook to push after each commit. To do this you'll need to add an executable `post-commit` script in your `.git/hooks` directory. For e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script that is called after a successful
# commit is made.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-commit".

git push --mirror remote
```

Where `remote` refers to the name of the remote repo that you are pushing to.

You can also setup `cron` to execute this script every hour if you wish.

**Update**

Mercurial has hooks too (but of course). Here is the [relevant documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks). I haven't used Mercurial so you'll have to work it out yourself.

Comment: `-f` is quite dangerous. Don't do that.

Comment: --mirror is very dangerous and I'm not sure it's what you want.  If you aren't up-to-date, you'll crush other peoples changes.